# Getting an error 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setAttribute')' while setting an attribute for the input webelement

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am trying to set an attribute for the input tag webelement for the value but actually I am getting this below error

Below is the code which I have written for this,

```
'document.getElementsByName('date')[0].setAttribute('value','2022-11-29');'
```

and the below error is getting

[image]

Can some one help with this,

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems that there is no element with the name "date" on the page.

Maybe you could also try `document.getElementsByName("date")[0].value = "2022-11-29"` ?

although i think the problem is with the selector itself

Comment: I have tried as you said but I am getting this error 'TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')'. And one more thing the above statement which I mentioned earlier I am able to execute through console.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from the error description that when

```
document.getElementsByName('date')[0].setAttribute('value','2022-11-29');
```

is executed there is no element with the name attribute === 'date'.

Try to execute

```
document.getElementsByName('date')
```

It should return NodeList which should contain necessary element (it is, presumably, empty which is the root of the error).

As stated in one of the answers, you could also modify the value of the element by:

```
document.getElementsByName("elementName")[0].value = 'newValue'
```

But be aware that it modifies the value of the element and not the value attribute of the element.

So, it's easy to `console.dir` that element and look that it has **value** property (which is changed by direct assignment to it) and **attributes** property which is NamedNodeMap object that contains the element's attributes (which properties are assigned by **setAttribute** method).